# MP3 file not playing in Iphone/Ipad

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I am palying MP3 files in my application using code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"congratulation.MP3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[audioPlayer play];
```

I am playing 15 MP3 files
All playing well, but one file is not playing it is playing very well i itunes but not in my app
Any solution for this strange problem.

Amit Battan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to replace the MP3 files